# How to start up MySQL workbench and connection for beginners?

Tags: mysql, sql, connection

I need a quick and easy way to import MS Excel databases and query them with PL/SQL for a class assignment. So far I've tried downloading MySQL Workbench and SQL Developer based on my class recommendations. MySQL Workbench looks simpler so I'm trying to learn to use that.

I'm completely lost on how to get started. Is it required for me to connect to a SQL database server before importing data? If so, how do I create one? I'm working off of my laptop and again, this is just for class so I don't need anything fancy.

I apologize for the very basic questions, as I have just started with learning databases. I researched for 2+ hours trying to figure out what to do, as my class resources aren't helpful and I must not be googling correctly as I can't find answers. If it's helpful at all, I've been successfully working with MS Access for SQL queries, so I'm comfortable with the environment. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

xampp is provides a control panel for start/stop the mysql server, you can download xampp from [here](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html). After installing xampp set the enviroment variable in your system for recognizing mysql commnad in your command prompt.

you can access mysql command line in your command prompt like this,

```
mysql -u root
```